# getting error message showing : parameter is not valid

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Currently im trying on this code..im still getting error : parameter is not valid

I want to display image from access database using vb.net. 
i saved image in access in OLE object.. i want to displayed it in PictureBox2.text
the name of column in access for image is : PicFile 
I can see the image in database as a long binary data but i cant display it in VB.net

```
Private Sub GetImageFrmDB()
    Try


        Cn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Final year stuff\BookStoreDb.mdb;")
        Cn.Open()
        str = "SELECT PicFile FROM Book_data WHERE ISBN='9780486407722'"

        Command = New OleDbCommand(str, Cn)
        Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        'Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISBN", Isbn_.Text)
        dr = Command.ExecuteReader()

        If dr.Read Then
            Dim imgByte() As Byte
            Try
                imgByte = CType(dr("PicFile"), Byte())
                Dim stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream(imgByte)
                Dim bm As New Bitmap(stream)
                stream.Close()

            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

            End Try
        End If
        dr.Close()
        Cn.Close()
        Command.Dispose()
        Cn.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: what line does the error happen on?  what column type is ISBN?

Comment: ISBN- Text .. I just referring to get the image..im not sure where does the error occur

Comment: The only thing we can suggest is that picFile, Book_data or ISBN are fields or tables that are either misspelled or don't exist.  You aren't doing anything with your bitmap, by the way.

Comment: get rid of the Try/Catch and it will tell you the exact line of the error

Comment: @Plutonix I think that error can only come from `dr = Command.ExecuteReader()`

Comment: if i take out line `dr = Command.ExecuteReader()` it shows error :object reference not set to an instance of an object at line `If dr.Read Then`

Comment: If you take out that line, nothing happens in that method.

Comment: turn on option strict, then quadruple check the table name, the PicFile column name, the ISBN column name (in that same table) and that ISBN is indeed text

Comment: i dint get such error after turn on the option strict `Plutonix`

Comment: Out of curiosity, how big is that image that you want to load in memory?. I have a suspicion. `Parameter is not valid` is a message thrown sometimes when there is something wrong in graphics.

Comment: You might consider uploading your .mdb file to a site like [wikisend.com](http://wikisend.com) and posting a download link here so others could try to recreate your issue.

Comment: i trying to save jpeg images ..size - 218kb

Comment: Rereading your question. You say that your image are stored as Ole Object. You cannot read back them in that way. `Parameter is not valid` comes from the Bitmap creation because your bytes are not recognized as valid image.

Comment: @Steve My interpretation of the question is that the images are stored in a field of type `OLE Object` but the images appear in Datasheet view as "Long binary data", suggesting that they are raw binary data, not OLE-wrapped objects.

Comment: @user3726806 No, not the .vb code, the .mdb database file.

Comment: `steve` - can i change bitmap to binaryreader?

Comment: If you cannot change the way in which the bitmap or jpg are stored to your database then the only option is to strip away the OleDBHeader from your byte array. I have found some code but it is in C#, trying to translate it

Comment: @user3726806 The .mdb file you uploaded contains a single table named [login] that has nothing to do with the issue you are trying to address with this question.

Comment: I have an Access DB where the col is defined as OLE Object, but the view of it in Access is "Long Binary Data", OleDbDataReader fetches it fine.  That could be version dependent though.  Mine is roughly the same version as this one.

Comment: No more time, hope this helps http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/88e07634-16e8-4e2b-8443-dc0a874d70d3/reading-an-ole-object-field-in-a-ms-access-database?forum=adodotnetdataproviders

Comment: `Gord Thompson` this is the file http://wikisend.com/download/463482/BookStoreDb.mdb

Comment: i can save image in access as long binary data - OLE Object but i unable to display.. i put `binaryreader` and take out the `bitmap`

Answer (score 0):

The code that inserted the data into the [PicFile] field did not store the *contents* of the image file, it stored (a Unicode representation of) the local *path* to the image file.

[image: hex.png]

That is obviously not valid image *data*, so trying to convert it with `New Bitmap(stream)` or use it in `Image.FromStream(stream)` is triggering a "Parameter is not valid" error because `stream` (the parameter) does not contain bytes representing a valid image.

So, you will need to fix the code that *writes* the image data into the database before you can fix the code that reads it back again.